# Heavy water dielectric constant

Tags: physical-chemistry, water

Why is heavy water less dielectric than normal water?
Is it because of the fact that heavy water is more denser? I think it so because the dipole moment of heavy water is greater than normal water?

Comment: Greater dipole moment would imply greater dielectric constant in D2O. But its dipole moment is not any significantly greater, nor is its dielectric constant lower than those of H2O. There is no point in discussing a less-than-1% difference. Think of them as identical.